# Parola di origine giapponese che è entrata per prima nella lingua italiana

Tags: etymology, history

Leggendo [questa domanda](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/26259/19075) mi è venuta la curiosità di sapere qualcosa sui primi giapponesismi nella lingua italiana.

Secondo [questa risposta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/26261/19075), i termini di origine giapponese che prima sono entrati nella lingua spagnola (cioè, i primi di cui si hanno documenti scritti in castigliano) sono "bonzo" e "catana" (ambedue l'hanno fatto nel 1580). Non so se esistano studi di giapponesismi nella lingua italiana simili a quel che si menziona in quel post, ma controllando sul [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI02/00000311.jpg) ho visto che "bonzo" è datato come del 1570. *Lo Zingarelli* che ho su Kindle riporta 1549 per la prima attestazione di "bonzo".

Invece, si è cominciato a usare la parola ["catana"](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI02/00000874.jpg) in italiano più tardi, secondo *lo Zingarelli* nel Seicento (infatti, il   *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana* cita una frase di [Francesco Carletti](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI_indice_autori/00069.jpg)).

Dunque, la mia domanda sarebbe: qual è il vocabolo di origine giapponese che appare per primo in documenti scritti in italiano? Si tratta del sostantivo "bonzo"?

Answer (score 3):

Lo metto come risposta, anche se so che andrà integrata da altre.

Paolo Zolli, in *Le parole straniere* (Zanichelli 1976, quindi non recentissimo), parlando alle pp. 103-4 dei nipponismi, scrive:

> Fin dal XIV secolo sarebbe entrato in italiano (se l'attestazione riportata dai dizionari storici non è un falso), il nome della *soia*, ‘erba cespugliosa delle leguminose ...’; nel XVII secolo è entrata la voce *catana* ...

Dopo di che, menziona le parole entrate nell'uso italiano tra la fine dell'Ottocento e l'inizio del Novecento (*aucuba*, *cachi*, *chimono*, *samurai*) e così via, con vari ingressi durante e dopo la Seconda guerra mondiale (*kamikaze* e vari termini relativi alle arti marziali).

Sulla soia, però, lo Zingarelli dà come data di prima attestazione addirittura il 1895, mentre nel GDLI, pur non dando una data specifica, il primo esempio riportato è addirittura novecentesco. Sarebbe interessante capire la storia del presunto falso.

Quindi allo stato attuale la classifica sarebbe:

1. *soia* (XIV secolo oppure 1895)
2. *bonzo* (1549, una lettera di s. Francesco Saverio)
3. *catana* (prima del 1636; di recente più spesso *katana*, attestata dal 1912)

Comment: Immagino che l'uso di "catana" di prima del 1636 sia la frase di F. Carletti riportata dal GDLI.

Comment: @Charo: Penso anch'io: lo Zingarelli dà solo “av. 1636”, e quindi probabilmente non si conosce la data di quello scritto, ma la morte dell'autore dà un terminus ante quem.

Comment: E l'attestazione di "soia" immagino sia questa: http://www.lessicografia.it/Controller?lemma=soia.

Comment: Ah, bravissima, @Charo, non avevo pensato a guardare il vocabolario della Crusca. Se lo registrano fin dalla prima edizione, sicuramente, falsi storici o no, il termine sarà ben precedente al 1895!

Comment: ...sempre che non sia un omografo, perché la “sorta di droga” appare nella stessa voce dedicata a “soia” nel senso di “seta”, dal francese _soie_. Chissà che cosa aveva in mente Maestro Aldobrandino.

Comment: È interessante [questo](https://iris.unito.it/retrieve/handle/2318/151098/26583/Postprint%2520Noto%2520Miscellanea%2520Massobrio.pdf).

Comment: Il provenzalista Seicentesco Francesco Redi fece un lavoro preparatorio per la terza edizione del *Vocabolario degli Accademici della Crusca* e scrisse: «Questo *agalloco* è la stessa cosa del *Siloe* del *Vocabolario*. [...] Nell’esemplo di *Siloe* del 
Maestro Aldobrandino citato dal *Vocabolario* vi è la voce *Soie* [sottolineato nell’originale]: è 
scorrezzione e dee dirsi *Seta* [idem] ché così si legge in tutti quanti i miei testi a penna. Si raggiusti anco alla voce *Soia*. *Soia* sta bene ed è provenzalismo *Soie* [*idem*].»

Comment: Nell'articolo si afferma: "«Provenzalismo» è verosimilmente scorso di penna per “francesismo”." Quindi, a quanto pare, la "soia" del Maestro Aldobrandino era un francesismo (col significato di "seta") e non un giapponesismo.

Comment: La "soia" del vocabolario della Crusca, col significato di "spezia orientale", appare anche sul [GDLI](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI19/00000302.jpg) come di "etimo incerto".

Comment: A quanto pare, questa frase fu scritta da [Zucchero Bencivenni](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI_indice_autori/00040.jpg) (prosegue [qui](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI_indice_autori/00041.jpg)) (XIV secolo) traducendo al Maestro Aldobrandini, che scrisse le sue opere in francese. La "soia" del libro che hai citato nella tua risposta molto probabilmente sia questa spezia orientale: il dubbio non è tanto se ci sia un'attestazione del XIV secolo, ma se questo termine (o il francese "soie" del Maestro Aldobrandino, se veramente scrisse "soie") sia veramente di origine giapponese.

Comment: Ah, ecco la [frase del Maestro Aldobrandino](https://fr.m.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:Aldebrandin_de_Sienne-Le_r%C3%A9gime_du_corps,_1911.djvu/197): 
«Coses caudes por user à chiaus ki ont le cuer froit si est: ecidoiare, musc, ambre, soie, safran, girofles, siloes, melise, cardamon, cubebes, fuelles de citre, fuelles <indes,> enula».

Comment: Mi chiedo come si tradusse questa frase in [catalano](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aldobrandino_da_Siena).