# A quali sostantivi della frase si può riferire l'aggettivo "primo" contenuto nelle locuzioni "per primo", "per prima", "per primi" e "per prime"?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives, adverbs, agreement

In [questo post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/11440/707) avevo usato l'avverbio "prima" un paio di volte, ma poi mi sono state corrette in "per primo/a". Adesso sto cercando di capire la ragione di questa sostituzione e di vedere quando devo usare "per primo" e quando "per prima", "per primi" o "per prime".

Prima di tutto, in quel post penso di aver scritto "prima" per influenza di un uso dell'avverbio catalano "primer", che ho pensato erroneamente si potesse sempre tradurre nell'italiano moderno con l'avverbio italiano "prima".

Come potete vedere sul [*Diccionari de l'Institut d'Estudis Catalans*](https://dlc.iec.cat/Results?IdE=0108843&DecEntradaText=primer%C2%B9&AllInfoMorf=False&OperEntrada=0&OperDef=0&OperEx=0&OperSubEntrada=0&OperAreaTematica=0&InfoMorfType=0&OperCatGram=False&AccentSen=False&CurrentPage=0&refineSearch=0), tale avverbio può avere il significato di "la prima volta" ("la primera vegada") come, ad esempio, in questa frase

> La casa on primer vaig viure

che adesso immagino possa essere tradotta come "La casa dove sono vissuto/a per prima" (la frase in catalano significa letteralmente "La casa dove vissi prima di farlo in qualsiasi altra").

In [quest'altro dizionario](https://www.diccionaris.cat/index.php?diccionario=77&empieza=empieza&palabra=Primers&imprimir=N) appare un altro esempio simile:

> La fàbrica on primer vaig treballar era prop de Barcelona.

La persona che ha formulato questa frase sta parlando del suo primo lavoro. Ecco il mio tentativo di traduzione in italiano: "La fabbrica dove lavorai per prima era vicino a Barcellona".

Anche in castigliano si usa l'avverbio "primero" con lo stesso significato, come, per esempio, in questa [frase](https://www.launion.com.mx/blogs/ciencia/noticias/117441-la-ia-de-google-ayuda-a-la-nasa-a-encontrar-un-nuevo-sistema-estelar.html):

> El exoplaneta que primero descubrió el telescopio Kepler fue precisamente Kepler-90i, [...].

Il suo significato letterale è questo: "L'esopianeta che il telescopio Kepler scoprì prima di qualsiasi altro fu appunto il Kepler-90i, [...]". Io renderei questa frase in italiano così:  "L'esopianeta che il telescopio Kepler scoprì per primo fu appunto il Kepler-90i, [...]".

Ora, ricercando sul [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/prima1) ho trovato questa accezione dell'avverbio "prima"

> **2**. ant. La prima volta, per la prima volta: *non è molto numero d’anni passato, che appariro p. questi poete volgari* (Dante)

che appare, però, con la marca "ant.", quindi penso sia un uso arcaico e che oggi si direbbe "che questi poeti (che scrivevano in volgare) apparvero per primi".

È così? Penso di sì perché, infatti, ho trovato un'altro esempio di uso dell'avverbio "pria" nel canto XVII del *Paradiso*,  nelle parole dette da Cacciaguida a Dante come predizione del suo esilio (versi 55-57, bellissimi, che esprimono  magistralmente il dolore sofferto dall'autore; il grassetto è sempre mio):

> Tu lascerai ogne cosa diletta
>             più caramente; e questo è quello strale
>             che l’arco de lo essilio pria saetta.

E nelle note di Anna Maria Chiavacci Leonardi (Mondadori) al verso 57 si legge:

> pria: per primo; altri dolori seguiranno, come ora si dirà, ma questo, il primo, della separazione irrevocabile, è anche il più amaro.

Quindi, oggi, invece di "pria" si userebbe la locuzione "per primo" con lo stesso significato.

Immagino che sia anche questa la ragione delle correzioni nel mio post: le versioni che avevo scritto io corrisponderebbero a un uso arcaico dell'avverbio "prima" che oggigiorno sembra bizzarro. Cioè, nell'italiano moderno si renderebbero in questo modo:

> Parola di origine giapponese che prima è entrata nella lingua italiana  --> Parola di origine giapponese che è entrata **per prima** nella lingua italiana

e anche

> qual è il vocabolo di origine giapponese che prima appare in documenti scritti in italiano? --> qual è il vocabolo di origine giapponese che appare **per primo** in documenti scritti in italiano?

Poi, non capivo
perché nel primo caso è "per prima" e nel secondo è "per primo", ma adesso penso che sia perché "prima" e "primo" sono aggettivi che fanno riferimento a "parola" e "vocabolo" rispettivamente.

Anche  nel racconto *Vanadio* dal libro *Il sistema periodico*, di Primo Levi, ho trovato un esempio di uso di "per primi" che non riesco a capire bene (il testo fa riferimento all'esperienza dell'autore in laboratorio ad Auschwitz; il grassetto è mio):

> A volte veniva un SS dalla faccia di pietra, altre volte un vecchio soldatino della Territoriale spaurito come un sorcio, altre ancora un borghese. Il borghese che compariva piú sovente veniva chiamato Doktor Müller. 
>       Doveva essere piuttosto autorevole, perché tutti lo salutavano **per primi**. Era un uomo alto e corpulento, sui quarant’anni, dall’aspetto piuttosto rozzo che raffinato; [...].

Non capisco perché si usa "per primi" e non "per primo" se la frase vuol dire che il  Doktor Müller era il primo ad essere salutato, nello stesso modo che, in una frase precedente, la parola di origine giapponese è la prima ad essere entrata nella lingua italiana. Come posso sapere con quale nome devo accordare l'aggettivo "primo" in queste locuzioni? Perché nella frase tratta dal racconto di Levi si fa con "tutti" (quelli che salutano) e non con il pronome "lo" (il Doktor Müller)?

Dai commenti alla domanda mi è sembrato intendere che gli esempi che ho messo sulla casa e sulla fabbrica (e anche quello sull'esopianeta?) non si renderebbero in italiano con le locuzioni "per prima" e "per primi": non riesco proprio a capire perché è così e invece Primo Levi usa "per primi" per indicare che, di tutte le persone che arrivavano in laboratorio ad Auschwitz, quella salutata prima di qualsiasi altra era il Doktor Müller
(immagino, ma forse il problema è che non capisco il significato di questa frase: purtroppo, non c'è più contesto che possa aggiungere e che ne possa chiarire il senso).

L'unica spiegazione che sono riuscita a trovare sul [lemma "primo" del *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI14/00000368.jpg) è che si tratta di costrutti di valore avverbiale. E la [voce "primo" del vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/primo/) indica soltanto che l'aggettivo "primo"

> con funzione appositiva, è di solito preceduto dalla prep. *per*: *ha parlato lui per p.*, o *lei per prima*; *sono io che l’ho saputo per primo*.

In generale, potreste spiegare come si usano le locuzioni "per primo", "per prima", "per primi" e "per prime", cioè, a quale sostantivo della frase si riferisce e si accorda
l'aggetivo "primo" che contengono?

**Giusto per chiarire**: non ho dubbi sull'uso e su come si deve accordare l'aggettivo "primo" quando non fa parte di queste locuzioni. Capisco anche come si usa l'avverbio "prima" nell'italiano moderno e che si tratta di un uso con un senso diverso di quello delle locuzioni "per primo", "per prima", "per primi" e "per prime": il mio dubbio non è quale sia la differenza di significato tra questi (questo lo comprendo senza problema).
Cioè, capisco la differenza tra "Sono arrivato per primo" e "Sono arrivato prima di mezzanotte/te/...".

Capisco anche che se l'aggettivo "primo" che appare in queste locuzioni qualifica "parola", allora si deve accordare in genere e numero  con "parola"; se si riferisce a  "vocabolo", deve concordare con "vocabolo"; ecc. Questo è così in tutte le lingue romanze e sarebbe un dubbio di grammatica molto elementare. Non è questo il mio dubbio. Il mio problema è: **a quali sostantivi della frase può riferirsi l'aggettivo "primo" di "per primo/a/e/i" e a quali no?**

---

## Aggiornamento:

Siccome, passati quasi sette mesi, la domanda continua senza risposta, ho cercato altri esempi di uso di queste locuzioni per vedere se così riesco a intuire il suo funzionamento.   Eccone alcuni (il grassetto è sempre mio):

- Marta  entrò  **per  prima**  nella  mac­china,  sedette  accanto  al  volante  e  posò  sulle  ginocchia il  fagotto  del  bimbo  il  quale  si  era  destato  e,  serio,  con
  gli  occhi  spalancati  e  pensosi,  pareva  osservare  tutte  le  nuove e strane cose che lo circondavano ([Moravia](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI05/00000584.jpg)).
- Pelle  che,  dopo  essere  stata  sotto­
  posta   ai   trattamenti   preliminari   della   concia, viene   stesa   **per   prima**   sul   cavalletto   e   sopra la   quale  vengono   poi  stese  altre  pelli  che   sono sottoposte agli stessi trattamenti ([un'accezione di "letto" sul *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI08/00001000.jpg)).
- Lanciavamo  una  moneta  racco­gliendola  nel  palmo  della  mano  per  indovinare  il  sesso  del  nascituro.  Giorgio  diceva: – È  una  cosa  importante  diven­tare padre. –Rideva **per primo**, commosso e intimidito ([Pratolini](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI14/00000368.jpg)).
- Quella  in  cui si  attacca  **per  primi** il  nemico,  o,  viceversa,  si scende in campo per rintuzzare la sua offensiva,
  senza prendere alcuna iniziativa ([definizione di "guerra offensiva o difensiva" sul *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI07/00000159.jpg)).
- I futuristi hanno  visto  **per  primi**  nella  macchina  oltre  che  la  più meravigliosa   conquista   utilitaria   dell’umanità,   anche   la sintesi  della  nuova  estetica  che  cambierà  la  faccia  del mondo ([*Manifesti  futuristi*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI06/00000519.jpg)).
- Diritto dei   signori   feudali   di   possedere   **per   primi**  le spose  dei  loro  vassalli  e  servi  nella  notte  nuziale, o   di   esigere,   in   sua   vece,   il   pagamento   di   una
  tassa   o   la   prestazione   di   un   servizio   da   parte dello   sposo   (e   secondo   la   moderna   critica   sto­rica   tale   diritto   non   è   mai   esistito   come   vero istituto   giuridico   – anche   se   non   si   escludono
  abusi   in   tal   senso  –,  ed   esso   è   stato   affermato acriticamente  dagli  scrittori  illuministi  sulla  base di racconti e leggende dell’età rinascimentale) ([definizione di "ius primae   noctis  o jus  cunnatici" sul *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI08/00000643.jpg).
- Con riferimento  a  cose  o  persone  con  le  quali  è impossibile   stabilire   un   rapporto   se  non prendendone  **per  primi** l’iniziativa [...] ([definizione di "essere come la montagna di Maometto" sul *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI10/00000846.jpg).
- Questo  fenomeno  di  ‘muta­zione’  o  ‘rotazione’  (in  tedesco  ‘Lautverschiebung’),
  α + β - γ,  investe  **per  primi**  i  dialetti  del  gruppo  meridionale  cui  appartiene il longobardo ([Avalle](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI17/00138.jpg)).
- E  le  cose  sacrificate  **per  prime**  sono  le  convenzioni  più squisitamente   civili;   la   cultura   in   quanto   educazione   e
  perfezione  interiore,  in  quanto  equilibrio;  e  il  rispetto  della persona  umana;  e  la  solidarietà;  e  il  pudore  della  propria
  ricchezza e felicità ([Alvaro](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI03/00001051.jpg)).
- Esempligrazia,  quelle  che  io  ho  visto  **per  prime** erano  queste  campagne  e  queste  marine  di  Romagna: e  ogni  volta  che  le  rivedo  mi  sento  effettivamente  come tornare  nuovo  e  verde  e  ogni  volta  dentro  di  me  qualche cosa batte puerilmente le mani ([Baldini](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI05/00000332.jpg)).
- ‘  Perine  dolci  ’:  specie  di  pere  pic­cole  che  vengono  **per  prime** ([Tommaseo](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI12/00001092.jpg)).

Quello che mi è sembrato di capire:

Si tratta di locuzioni con valore avverbiale che determinano un verbo in qualsiasi modo, inclusi il participio, il gerundio e l'infinito. Il verbo può anche essere coniugato in una forma impersonale o con il "si passivante". Ma, allo stesso tempo, queste locuzioni contengono un aggettivo, "primo", che  qualifica un sostantivo e che deve essere accordato in genere e numero con questo sostantivo. Quindi, possiamo dire che queste locuzioni determinano un verbo, a cui chiamerò il "verbo associato", e qualificano un sostantivo allo stesso tempo. Il problema è vedere quali sostantivi possono qualificare.

Per il momento, non prendo in considerazione i casi in cui il verbo è al participio, al gerundio, all'infinito o è coniugato in una forma impersonale o con il "si passivante (perché mi sembrano casi più complicati). Cerco di fare ipotesi per gli altri casi, basandomi negli esempi che ho citato sopra:

**• Ipotesi 1:** Queste locuzioni possono soltanto qualificare il soggetto del verbo associato.

Problema: gli esempi di Avalle e Baldini smentiscono questa ipotesi.

**• Ipotesi 2:** Queste locuzioni possono soltanto qualificare il soggetto o il complemento oggetto diretto del verbo associato.

Questo spiegherebbe perché gli esempi in catalano della casa e della fabbrica non si possono rendere in italiano con queste locuzioni.

Nella frase "la casa dove sono vissuta per prima", "sono vissuta" non ha complemento oggetto, quindi "prima" qualificherebbe al soggetto di "sono vissuta" e il significato sarebbe "sono stata la prima persona a vivere in quella casa". Nello stesso modo "lavorai per prima" implicherebbe che il soggetto di "lavorai" è femminile e vorrebbe dire "sono stata la prima persona a lavorare".

L'esempio dell'esopianeta, però, si dovrebbe poter rendere in questo modo perché in questo caso si qualifica il complemento oggetto diretto di "scoprì": "L'esopianeta che il telescopio Kepler scoprì per primo fu appunto il Kepler-90i".

Anche l'esempio di Dante si dovrebbe poter riscrivere in questo modo: "che questi poeti apparvero per primi" (in questo caso "primi" qualifica al soggetto di "apparvero").

Poi c'è l'esempio di Primo Levi: "tutti lo salutavano per primi". In questo caso "primi" qualifica al soggetto "tutti". Ma, se l'ipotesi 2 non è sbagliata, si dovrebbe poter riscrivere la frase di Primo Levi in questo modo, magari modificandone il significato: "Doveva essere piuttosto autorevole, perché tutti lo salutavano per primo". È veramente così?

Tuttavia, devo dire che la frase di Primo Levi con "primi" mi sembra difficile da capire (perché "tutti" sarebbero "primi"?) e invece riscritta nel modo in cui l'ho fatto io mi sembra più naturale (ma, come ho detto, forse il senso cambia).

**• Ipotesi 3:** Considero ora il caso di un verbo associato coniugato in una forma con il "si passivante", come nell'esempio della definizione di "guerra offensiva" ("si attacca il nemico"). Veramente è difficile per me fare un'ipotesi su questo caso perché sono riuscita soltanto a trovarne un esempio (ho ricercato anche su Google libri, ma non è così semplice individuare questi esempi).
Possiamo dire che un costrutto con il "si passivante" ha un soggetto grammaticale e anche, per così chiamarlo, un "soggetto logico". Per esempio, il soggetto grammaticale di "si parla italiano" è "italiano", ma questa frase, dipendendo dal contesto, può significare più o meno "alcuni parlano italiano", "tutti parlano italiano" o "noi parliamo italiano"  e, allora, il "soggetto logico" sarebbe "alcuni", "tutti" o "noi".

Ecco la mia ipotesi (molto azzardata perché ho soltanto un esempio): queste locuzioni possono soltanto qualificare il "soggetto logico" o il soggetto grammaticale del verbo associato coniugato con il "si passivante". Quando qualificano il soggetto logico la forma è sempre "per primi", con l'aggettivo al maschile plurale.

Nell'esempio che ho trovato, "per primi" modificherebbe il "soggetto logico". Se l'ipotesi non è sbagliata, si dovrebbe anche poter dire "si attacca **per primo** il nemico", con "primo" accordato con il soggetto grammaticale, "il nemico". In questo caso, accade come nell'esempio di Primo Levi: la frase con "per primi" della definizione del dizionario mi sembra difficile di capire; la frase che ho appena scritto io mi sembra (forse erroneamente) più naturale; non sono sicura se ci sia qualche differenza di significato tra le due frasi.

**• Ipotesi 4:** Adesso considero la situazione di un participio passato come verbo associato. Anche qui è azzardato fare un'ipotesi perché ho trovato soltanto un esempio: la frase di Alvaro.

Ecco la mia ipotesi: nelle frasi in cui appaiono queste locuzioni, il participio ha valore aggettivale. Se pensato come aggettivo, questo participio qualifica un sostantivo (nell'esempio, "cose sacrificate", il sostantivo è "cose"). L'aggettivo "primo" di queste locuzioni si riferisce sempre a questo sostantivo e si deve accordare con questo sostantivo. Nell'esempio

> E le cose sacrificate per prime sono [...]

"prime" si riferisce e si accorda con "cose".

**• Ipotesi 5:** Mi riferisco ora al caso in cui il verbo associato è all'infinito. Una volta in più, purtroppo, sono riuscita a trovarne soltanto un esempio (la definizione di "ius primae noctis"). Di nuovo si tratta di qualcosa di molto azzardato.

La mia ipotesi: questo verbo all'infinito ha un "soggetto logico" e può avere un complemento oggetto diretto.

Nell'esempio

> Diritto dei signori feudali di possedere per primi le spose dei loro vassalli e servi [...]

il "soggetto logico" di "possedere" è "signori feudali" e il complemento oggetto diretto è "le spose dei loro vassalli e servi".

L'ipotesi sarebbe che queste locuzioni possono soltanto qualificare il "soggetto logico" (come accade appunto nell'esempio della definizione del dizionario, in cui "primi" si riferisce a "signori feudali") o il complemento oggetto diretto (se esiste nella frase) del verbo associato all'infinito.

Cerco d'inventare un esempio in cui una di queste locuzione qualifica il complemento oggetto diretto (non so se avrà senso):

> Ho dato a Luigi la soddisfazione di poter vedere per prime le fotografie più belle del mio viaggio.

**• Ipotesi 6:** Ora tocca pensare al caso di un verbo associato nella forma di un gerundio. È anche difficile con unicamente un esempio: quello della definizione di "essere come la montagna di Maometto".

Come il caso del verbo all'infinito, questo verbo al gerundio ha un "soggetto logico" e può avere un complemento oggetto diretto.

Nell'esempio

> Con riferimento a cose o persone con le quali è impossibile stabilire un rapporto se non prendendone per primi l’iniziativa [...]

il "soggetto logico" di "prendendo" non è espresso in modo esplicito nella frase, ma possiamo pensare che è "noi". Il complemento oggetto diretto di "prendendo" è "l'iniziativa".

L'ipotesi sarebbe la stessa che ho fatto per il caso dell'infinito: queste locuzioni possono soltanto qualificare il "soggetto logico" (come accade appunto nell'esempio della definizione del dizionario, in cui "primi" si riferisce al soggetto logico "noi")  o il complemento oggetto diretto (se esiste nella frase) del verbo associato all'infinito.

Cerco d'inventare un esempio (che magari non avrà molto senso):

> Non si può avere nessuna soddisfazione nel guardare un sacco di fotografie se non vedendone per prime quelle più belle.

**• Ipotesi 7:** Questo è azzardatissimo perché non sono riuscita a trovare nessun esempio. Il verbo associato potrebbe anche essere in una forma impersonale.

Possiamo pensare che il verbo nella forma impersonale ha, per così chiamarlo, un "soggetto logico". L'ipotesi sarebbe che
queste locuzioni possono soltanto qualificare questo "soggetto logico" nella forma "per primi", con l'aggettivo al maschile plurale.

Cerco di inventare un esempio (che magari non ha molto senso):

> Quando si diventa dirigenti per primi in un'azienda, *<s>tutto sono difficoltà</s> tutto è difficile<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1. Mi sono accorta di questo sbaglio grazie alla risposta di @egreg.</sup>

**Aggiungo questo come spiegazione su cosa intendo dire con questa ultima frase** (dopo la risposta di @egreg):

Con questa frase, che magari non è ben costrutta o non ha nessun senso, voglio esprimere che, quando si è appena creata un'azienda, alcune persone devono essere le prime a ricoprire il ruolo di dirigenti. Questo sarebbe il senso della frase:

> Tutto è difficile per quelli che ricoprono per primi il ruolo di dirigenti di un'azienda.

So che è più facile ed elegante di formulare semplicemente questa ultima frase, ma ho cercato di inventare un esempio di uso di "per primi" (o "per primo", ecc.) con un verbo nella forma impersonale, se veramente questo costrutto si può fare. Forse sarebbe meglio riscriverlo in questo modo:

> Quando si ricopre per primi il ruolo di dirigenti  in un'azienda tutto è difficile.

La costruzione che appare in questa ultima frase, però, è quella del "si passivante".

Magari qualcuno di voi riesce a trovare un esempio migliore con un costrutto impersonale.

## Osservazione sulla risposta a questa domanda:

Può darsi che non sia possibile trovare una risposta "perfetta" a questa domanda (magari sì perché qualcuno di voi potrebbe avere accesso a fonti inaccessibili per me). Ma le risposte non del tutto complete o basate sull'esperienza di parlanti che hanno dimestichezza con i costrutti di cui si sta chiedendo sono anche utili (e ho l'impressione che siano più frequenti su altri siti SE dedicati alle lingue). Una risposta parziale che contenga

- controesempi a queste ipotesi (eccetto per l'ipotesi 1 per cui sono riuscita io stessa a trovarli)
- le vostre ipotesi sull'argomento
- un elenco di esempi di uso più completo di quello che ho riportato io o semplicemente qualche esempio per i casi per cui non sono riuscita a trovarne

sarà utilissima per me. È da molto tempo che cerco una risposta a questa e non sono riuscita a trovare nulla a riguardo.

Comment: Nelle due frasi concorda effettivamente una volta con “parola” e una volta con “vocabolo”.

Comment: Purtroppo ancora non conosco il catalano. La frase «La casa dove sono vissuto/a per prima» mi suona come: «Sono stata la prima persona a vivere in quella casa». È lo stesso senso del catalano? In ogni caso, quando si usa «per primo», quel “primo” è un aggettivo, quindi lo concordiamo con il nome a cui si riferisce. Nell’esempio “antico”: «questi poeti (che scrivevano in volgare) apparvero per primi» (maschile plurale). Invece, “prima” è avverbio, quindi non cambia.

Comment: @Benedetta: No, significa che è la prima casa che hai avuto. In [quest'altro dizionario](https://www.diccionaris.cat/index.php?diccionario=77&empieza=empieza&palabra=Primers&imprimir=N) appare un altro esempio simile: "la fàbrica on primer vaig treballar era prop de Barcelona": la persona che scrive sta parlando del suo primo lavoro.

Comment: @Benedetta: Ecco il mio tentativo di traduzione: la fabbrica dove lavorai per prima era vicino a Barcellona.

Comment: @Charo: mi suona di più così: La prima fabbrica dove lavorai era vicino a Barcellona. Oppure, se i lavori seguenti sono stati diversi: Il mio primo lavoro è stato in una fabbrica vicino a Barcellona.

Comment: Io credo che "per primo" sia da usare quando il significato della frase punta sull'ordine di oggetti, mentre userei "prima"  se si parla di posizione nel tempo.
Per cui  "è arrivato **prima** di me" , o "fra i corridori è arrivato **per primo**"

Comment: @ChristianL.: Qui il senso non è nessuno di quelli che hai detto. Si tratta anche di posizione nel tempo, ma significa "prima di qualsiasi altro", come nell'esempio della frase in spagnolo: prima di qualsiasi altro esopianeta, il telescopio Kepler scoprì il Kepler-90i. Poi, capisco perfettamente la differenza di significato tra i tuoi due esempi: non è questo il problema.

Comment: Concordo con Benedetta: il modo più naturale di esprimere quel concetto in italiano è "la prima casa/fabbrica in cui abbia abitato/lavorato". "La fabbrica dove lavorai per prima" suona piuttosto bizzarra ma il senso che le darei è "sono stata la prima a lavorare in quella fabbrica" e assumerei che tu sia una donna (o comunque che parli di te al femminile). Immagino che in questo caso l'uso differisca tra italiano e catalano.

Comment: A me sembra che i commenti spieghino abbastanza bene come funzionano le cose. La particella "per" serve per assegnare la parola "prima" (o primo) al soggetto/oggetto invece che al verbo (con *primo* non è strettamente indispensabile). Guarda queste due frasi: "Lui arrivò prima" e "Lui arrivò primo". Confronta con "Lei arrivò prima" e "Lei arrivò per prima".

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: Malgrado i commenti, per me la questione non è per niente chiara (e poi i commenti non sono mai o non dovrebbero essere mai una risposta).

Comment: E la risposta presente non si capisce?

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: La risposta si capisce, ma non risponde a quello che sto chiedendo. Non chiarisce i miei dubbi sull'argomento.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica:  Non riesco proprio a vedere quale conclusione dovrei trarre di «Guarda queste due frasi: "Lui arrivò prima" e "Lui arrivò primo". Confronta con "Lei arrivò prima" e "Lei arrivò per prima".»

Comment: @linuxfan:  Semplicemente la risposta non chiarisce i miei dubbi. Qual è il problema?

Comment: Credo che la frase di Levi significhi che tutti volevano essere i primi a salutare, facevan la gara a chi salutava prima (per primo). La frase di Dante potrebbe anche essere intesa come "non passarono molti anni prima che comparissero questi poeti". Un maggior contesto aiuterebbe: l'italiano di Dante è "strano" per i nostri giorni ma vedi che, solo variando l'ordine delle parole, la frase diventa molto normale.

Comment: Insisto. Qualche commento è stato utile per me? Sì, l'ho spiegato nella domanda. Tuttavia: 1) I commenti non sono mai una risposta (non dovrebbero esserlo secondo la documentazione ufficiale di SE). 2) La risposta del 22 gennaio non risponde a nulla di quello che sto chiedendo ed è questa la ragione per cui ho messo il bounty. Come ho detto, voglio incoraggiare ulteriori risposte seppur parziali, ma che mi aiutino a chiarire qualcosa, per piccola che sia, di quello che sto chiedendo.

Comment: “Quando si diventa dirigenti per primi in azienda, tutto sono difficoltà”;  secondo te “tutto sono difficoltà” è una frase corretta?

Comment: Sì, mi sono sbagliata, @Hachi, a causa di qualcosa che si usa nelle mie lingue, ma questo è già stato chiarito nella risposta di egreg. Non potevo correggere questa frase dopo la risposta di egreg.

Comment: Penso dovresti correggerla, altrimenti stride con il resto della tua domanda.

Comment: Va bene, @Hachi: ho cercato di farlo in modo che si possa capire perché egreg ha scritto tutto quello nella sua risposta.

Answer (score 2):

Se in italiano uso "prima" vuol dire che la confronto con qualcosa, con un certo momento:

> Parola di origine giapponese che prima è entrata nella lingua italiana

leggendo, mi viene da dire "prima di cosa?" Mettendo prima, mi aspetto che ci sia un momento nel tempo che sottintendiamo e dico che prima di quel momento la parola di origine giapponese è entrata nella lingua italiana. Per esempio: sto parlando in francese, ma prima ho parlato in italiano.

Se uso "per prima", non faccio nessun confronto: mi riferisco al primo utilizzo in assoluto che ne è stato fatto della parola nella lingua italiana.

Per fare un confronto, forse un po' forzato, con gli aggettivi, è la differenza che si tra il comparativo (più bello di...) e il superlativo (bellissimo).

Vorrei aggiungere un altro particolare: in italiano il "superlativo" di prima/o si rende anche con l'articolo (un po' come fanno il superlativo i francesi): "la prima casa dove ho vissuto" vuol dire la casa in cui ho vissuto quando sono nato. "la casa dove ho vissuto prima" vuol dire prima di ora, non necessariamente quando sono nato.

Notare la differenza tra "La prima casa dove ho vissuto" in cui si fa riferimento alla casa in cui ho vissuto alla nascita mentre "La casa in cui ho vissuto per primo" in cui si fa riferimento alla persona che ha vissuto in quella casa prima di ogni altri: io posso aver vissuto in altri luoghi, ma quando hanno costruito questa casa, il primo ad abitarci sono stato io.

Per quanto riguarda invece l'uso di "per primo" e di "per prima" è semplicemente per accordarli con il nome:

> Parola di origine giapponese che è entrata per prima nella lingua italiana

prima si accorda con "parola" che è femminile.

> il vocabolo di origine giapponese che appare per primo in documenti scritti in italiano

primo si accorda con "vocabolo" che è maschile.

La stessa cosa l'ho fatta poco sopra:

> mi riferisco al primo utilizzo

uso primo per accordare con "utilizzo" che è maschile.

Comment: Ma, allora, posso anche dire "La casa dove sono vissuto/a per prima", "L'esopianeta che il telescopio Kepler scoprì per primo fu appunto il Kepler-90i", "Non sono passati tanti anni da quando questi poeti apparvero per primi"?

Comment: Nota anche che la mia domanda riguarda soltanto l'uso delle locuzioni "per primo/a/i/e". Mi è chiaro come si deve fare l'accordo dell'aggettivo "primo". Mi è chiara anche la differenza di significato tra "per primo/a/i/e" e l'uso che si fa dell'avverbio "prima" nell'italiano di oggi.

Comment: "La casa dove sono vissuta per prima" vuol dire che sono stata la prima persona che ha abitato in quella casa. "La casa dove sono vissuta prima" vuol dire la casa dove abitavo prima della casa in cui abito attualmente. "L'esopianeta ..." vuol dire il primo esopianeta scoperto da Kepler. "non è molto numero d’anni passato, che appariro p. questi poete volgari" vuol dire che le poesie in volgare (in italiano al posto del latino) sono apparse appunto per prime, probabilmente sono state pubblicate prima di altre opere di Dante.

Comment: Purtroppo, ancora non riesco a capire come si usano "per primo/a/i/e". Perché "prima" nell'espressione "Parola di origine giapponese che è entrata per prima ..." fa riferimento a "parola", mentre invece in "La casa dove sono vissuta per prima" fa riferimento alla persona che scrive (una donna) e non può riferirsi a "la casa"?

Comment: In "La parola che è entrata per prima è stata ..." è composta da 2 frasi: "La parola è stata" e la derivata "che è entrata per prima" in cui il soggetto è "che", che fa riferimento a parola, femminile.
In "La casa dove sono vissuta per prima", prima fa riferimento sempre al soggetto "Io", quindi femminile per Charo o sarebbe maschile per me.

Comment: Veramente questa risposta non risponde a niente di quello che sto chiedendo nella domanda.

Comment: Riassunto di quello che spiega questa risposta: 1) Differenza di significato tra l'avverbio "prima" (nel modo come si usa nell'italiano moderno) e le locuzioni "per primo/a/i/e": questo non è stato mai il mio dubbio. 2) Qualcosa sull'uso e significato dell'aggettivo "primo/a": neanche questo è stato mai il mio dubbio. Capisco da molto tempo cosa significa e come si usa questo aggettivo. (Segue)

Comment: 3) L'aggettivo "primo" nelle locuzioni "per primo/a/i/e" (e anche l'aggettivo "primo" in generale) si deve accordare (in genere e numero) con il nome a cui si riferisce. Questa affermazione corrisponde a grammatica molto elementare. Funziona così in tutte le lingue romanze (in particolare, nelle mie lingue).

Answer (score 1):

Non vedo nulla di strano in

> (a) la parola giapponese che prima è entrata nella lingua italiana

dove *prima* è un normale aggettivo in funzione di apposizione. È lo stesso che

> (b) il rapinatore che quatto quatto era in attesa della vittima

Tuttavia, la costruzione (a) è desueta, probabilmente perché *prima* è anche un avverbio molto usato. Al posto di *prima* aggettivo in funzione di apposizione si adopera, al giorno d'oggi, la locuzione avverbiale *per prima*, con concordanza.

> Tutti lo salutavano per primi

significa che i lavoranti nel laboratorio erano i primi a salutare il dottore. Un ipotetico *tutti lo salutavano per primo* significherebbe che i lavoranti andavano a salutare il dottore prima di salutare chiunque altro.

Quanto alle abitazioni, *la casa in cui vissi per primo* (desueto: la casa in cui primo vissi*) si riferisce a una casa in cui nessun altro visse prima di me (maschile, perché il soggetto sono io, egreg; sarebbe femminile se il soggetto fossi tu, Charo). Al contrario, direi *passando per Papozze, ho visto la prima casa in cui vissi*.

<sup>Papozze è un piccolo paese in riva al Po, con una storia interessante: il centro sorgeva in area golenale e fu trasferito al di là dell'argine dopo l'alluvione del 1951. Ci nacque mia madre, ma andammo ad abitare là per motivi di lavoro di mio padre, lei si era trasferita *in* Adria da bambina.</sup>

La frase

> Non si può avere nessuna soddisfazione nel guardare un sacco di fotografie se non vedendone per prime quelle più belle.

non è del tutto idiomatica, ma non scorretta. Personalmente toglierei il pronome *ne*.

L'ultimo esempio

> Quando si diventa dirigenti per primi in un'azienda, tutto sono difficoltà.

è davvero sgrammaticato. Il *per primi* potrebbe essere *per la prima volta*, ma sarebbe già sottinteso in *diventa*; il verbo *sono* è sbagliato, perché *tutto* è singolare. Versioni più scorrevoli sarebbero

> Quando si diventa dirigenti in un'azienda, all'inizio tutto è difficile.
> Quando si diventa dirigenti in un'azienda per la prima volta, tutto è difficile.

Si può usare *difficoltà*? Sì, se proprio si vuole.

Comment: Grazie della risposta, @egreg! Perlomeno adesso ho imparato che si può dire "lo salutavano per primi" ("primi" qualifica il soggetto) e anche "lo salutavano per primo" ("primo" qualifica il complemento oggetto diretto), ma i sensi di queste due frasi sono diversi. Secondo me, però, una frase come "I lavoranti lo salutavano per primi" è più facile di capire perché se sono "tutti" quelli che sono "primi" a salutare, non ci sono persone che salutino dopo. Non importa, però.

Comment: Nel primo esempio di frase che hai riportato, "prima" è un aggettivo? O si tratterebbe di un uso arcaico dell'avverbio "prima" (quello della definizione del Treccani riportata nella domanda)?

Comment: @Charo Avverbio? Non con *che*, lo sarebbe con *dove*.

Comment: L'esempio di Dante, "che appariro prima questi poete volgari" è con "che". Ma forse si può interpretare sia come questo avverbio arcaico, sia come un aggettivo (come il "quato" del tuo esempio), non so.

Comment: Poi, capisco che nell'ultimo esempio della domanda a cui hai fatto riferimento avrei dovuto scrivere "tutto è difficile" (o magari anche "tutto è difficoltà"). Tuttavia, quello che volevo esprimere è diverso di quello che hai scritto nei tuoi ultimi esempi. Intendevo dire "tutto è difficile per le prime persone ad essere dirigenti in un'azienda" (aggiungo questo alla domanda). So che si tratta di qualcosa di molto forzato, ma cercavo di inventare un esempio di uso di "per primi" (o "per primo", ecc.) con un verbo nella forma impersonale, se veramente questo costrutto si può fare

Comment: Adesso mi sembra di capire che il senso della frase di Primo Levi è che tutti lo salutavano allo stesso tempo (così tutti erano i primi a salutare).

Comment: La frase "Non si può avere nessuna soddisfazione nel guardare un sacco di fotografie se non vedendo per prime quelle più belle" (so che si tratta di una sintassi molto ritorta, quindi non è bella, ma anche qui cercavo di inventare un esempio di uso di "per prime" con un gerundio) suona ancora poco idiomatica? O semplicemente sembra di sintassi ritorta?

Comment: @Charo 1. L'esempio di Dante è molto arcaico; 2. la frase sui dirigenti non ha senso se interpretata come *i primi a essere dirigenti d'azienda* (non è mai esistito il *primo* dirigente di un'azienda); 3. Il gerundio c'è, dov'è il problema?

Comment: Su 2: ho cercato di spiegarlo meglio nella domanda. Ma se la frase che ho inventato io non si capisce, mi pare abbastanza evidente che non abbia molto senso. Su 3: non c'è nessun problema. Cerco semplicemente di capire se  "Non si può avere nessuna soddisfazione nel guardare un sacco di fotografie se non vedendo per prime quelle più belle" suona non idiomatico o semplicemente sembra una frase di sintassi ritorta.

Comment: Non capisco cosa significhi il voto all'ultimo commento di @egreg che è appena apparso. Dovrei aggiungere qualche altro chiarimento?

Comment: Devo dire che questa risposta è stata per me molto più utile di quanto possa sembrare. Ho potuto capire che perlomeno alcune delle miei ipotesi hanno senso. E questo è per me davvero utile.