# Accordo di "per primo/a" con il soggetto o con l'oggetto diretto

Tags: word-usage, meaning, adjectives, adverbs, agreement

Si tratta di una domanda correlata a [questa](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/11442/), che è ancora senza una risposta completa.

In quella domanda ho citato questa terzina di Dante, di suprema bellezza e intensità:

> Tu lascerai ogne cosa diletta
>             più caramente; e questo è quello strale
>             che l’arco de lo essilio pria saetta.
>            
> (*Paradiso* XVII, 55-57).

Immaginate che io voglia parafrasare in italiano moderno il secondo emistichio, usando "freccia" al posto di "strale": come dovrei fare l'accordo della locuzione "per primo/a"? Con il soggetto "l'arco" o con l'oggetto diretto "la freccia"? Cioè, si dovrebbe dire

> e questa è la freccia che l'arco dell'esilio saetta per primo

oppure

> e questa è la freccia che l'arco dell'esilio saetta per prima?

Queste due mie frasi hanno significati diversi? Ho l'impressione che la risposta a questa ultima domanda sia affermativa, ma non ne sono del tutto sicura. La mia ipotesi è che, nel primo caso, sia implicito l'uso di parecchi archi e che l'espressione faccia riferimento al primo arco a essere utilizzato per lanciare una freccia, mentre il secondo si riferirebbe al primo dardo saettato da un arco usato per lanciare più di una freccia. È così?

Answer (score 1):

Sì, le due frasi hanno significato diverso:

"*e questa è la freccia che l'arco dell'esilio saetta per primo*" significa che l'arco è il primo a lanciare la freccia (e poi potrebbero esserci altri archi che la lanciano)

"*e questa è la freccia che l'arco dell'esilio saetta per prima*" significa che la freccia è la prima ad essere lanciata dall'arco (che poi potrebbe lanciarne anche altre, ma resta sempre lo stesso arco)

Nel caso citato, la parafrasi corretta è la seconda: l'abbandono delle cose care è la prima conseguenza (freccia) dell'esilio (arco), a cui ne potrebbero seguire altre (ad esempio, la difficoltà di vivere da straniero in terra straniera, il senso di impotenza nel vedere la propria patria in mano al "nemico", senza poter far nulla, etc.)

L'interpretazione corretta si può desumere dal contesto: innanzi tutto sarebbe assurdo pensare ad una stessa freccia scagliata più volte da archi diversi, quindi la metafora stessa, da sola, suggerisce che quel "*pria*" sia riferito allo strale e non all'arco.
In secondo luogo, proseguendo nella lettura dei versi successivi risulta evidente che Dante stia elencando una serie di conseguenze (che, nella metafora sono gli strali) dell'esilio (che nella metafore è l'arco), di cui l'abbandono di ciò che è caro è solo la prima:

> Tu lascerai ogne cosa diletta
> più caramente; e questo è quello strale
> che l’arco de lo essilio pria saetta. `[57]`
>
> Tu proverai sì come sa di sale
> lo pane altrui, e come è duro calle
> lo scendere e 'l salir per l'altrui scale.  `[60]`
>
> E quel che più ti graverà le spalle,
> sarà la compagnia malvagia e scempia
> con la qual tu cadrai in questa valle; `[63]`
>
> che tutta ingrata, tutta matta ed empia
> si farà contr’ a te; ma, poco appresso,
> ella, non tu, n’avrà rossa la tempia. `[66]`

(Dante, Paradiso, canto XVII, versi 55-66)

Comment: Va bene, ma per quale ragione, dal punto di vista linguistico (cioè, oltre alla consuetudine dei cacciatori con arco) la frase di Dante vorrebbe dire che c'è una prima freccia e poi altre e non un primo arco e poi altri?

Comment: Non è la consuetudine dei cacciatori ad indicare il senso della frase, è il contesto. Anche senza usare la metafora dell'arco e della freccia, in quel passaggio a Dante viene profetizzato il futuro esilio e le conseguenze che ne deriveranno. Se si prosegue nella lettura dei versi 58-66 si vede che vengono elencate altre conseguenze (altri strali). [Nota: ho eliminato i commenti scritti in precedenza, inserendoli nella risposta per renderla più chiara]

Comment: OK, ma, dal punto di vista linguistico (come ho detto prima, so che non è abituale) perché non pottebbero essere un secondo e un terzo arco a scagagliare delle frecce?

Comment: Perché il contesto dimostra che non è quello il significato. La lingua non è solo un insieme di regole univoche; chiedere perché quel "_pria_" si riferisca allo strale e non all'arco, senza considerare il contesto, è un po' come chiedere se "_ancora_" (preso così, singolarmente, al di fuori di qualsiasi contesto) sia da intendersi come avverbio (ancóra) o come nome (àncora).

Comment: Per fare un esempio assurdo: "_Maria mi ha portato una mela e l'ho mangiata_". Tecnicamente, non esiste una regola per cui il pronome `l(a)` si debba riferire sicuramente alla mela e non a Maria ma (salvo che il contesto suggerisca altrimenti) nessuno penserà mai che io abbia mangiato Maria anziché la mela. ;)

Comment: Altro esempio "_Tizio ha parlato per primo a Caio_" vuol dire che Tizio ha parlato prima a Caio e poi ad altri o che Tizio è stato il primo di molti a parlare a Caio? E' impossibile stabilirlo con certezza, senza un'adeguata contestualizzazione: "_Tizio ha parlato per primo a Caio, **quando ancora nessuno lo conosceva**_" o "_Tizio ha parlato per primo a Caio, **perché la sua opinione è quella che più conta per lui**_"